# Button got overlapped by the ListView's Data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-layout-weight

I would like to know the possibilities to create a button after Listview without assiging any hardcore value to its height.

What happened is my button gets overlapped by the Listview when the no of rows exceeds say 14 or 15.For my layout mostly i'm using LinearLayout as i feel little comfortable with it.

Here i'm attaching my layout's xml snippet and the image.Please have a look and leave your comments and way to get rid of the above mentioned situation.

Thanks in advace guys.

layout xml file(*Snippet*)

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_full"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/invScanType" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_fullTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                 >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/itemno"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pick_seq"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseordqty"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseshpqty"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/uom"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseshipvia"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/msecomments"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_msefull"
                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_mse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_mseExit"
            style="@style/ButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action_exit_in" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Layout image

[image]

Here i'want to restrict my Listview height so that button doesn't Overlapped when Listview content is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in a vertical `LinearLayout`.
Set the `height` of the `HorizontalScrollView` to `0dp` and the `weight` to `1`.

Comment: Its working perfectly but when listview's items are small then the button also moves upward. Tried using android:layoput_gravity="bottom" but does'n makes any sense to my layout.  @ pdegand59